# what's the easiest way to go from non-responsive to responsive in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

when i designed my website, i made the mistake of going non-responsive (http://getbootstrap.com/examples/non-responsive/) because i didn't know much about it. now, i realize that was a mistake and i'd like to correct it. my main problems are:

1. i use `col-xs` all throughout the website.
2. besides the `bootstrap.min.css` file, i use a custom CSS file with the following:

for the default CSS, i use:

```
body {
  min-width: 970px;
}
...
```

which is pretty similar to http://getbootstrap.com/examples/non-responsive/non-responsive.css

and then farther down I have:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) { 
(some more custom CSS here, mainly font sizes)
}
```

what's the easiest way for me to convert this website to responsive? i am guessing i might need to edit all the tags and add `col-md`, `col-lg`, am i correct?

any help and advice would be greatly appreciated to correct this dummy's big mistake :)

Comment: You should modify your CSS with properties like max-width, instead of change your classes. The classes are ok. Can you give us a link to the website?

Answer (score 0):

short explanation of the grid-system in bootstrap:

like you already know there are several classes for different viewports.

but you don't need all of them actually:

for example - if you have 3x col-lg-4 and resize your browser under 1170px these boxes won't float, they will break.

if you have 3x col-md-4 and resize browser under 970px these boxes won't float anymore.

col-xs will always float and is always horizontal and will never break.

You also forgot to mention if you want to go full-fluid responsive or breakpoint-responsive what would make a difference in using the .container-classes.

.container-fluid is for full fluid design and .container is for pages with 1170px max width.

Comment: Thank you very much for that explanation! I think breakpoint responsive would be most effective and possibly easier to convert. The one I use right now is `.container`

Comment: you should also delete all (most) of your fixed width from your css. for example this body { min-width: 970px; } - use the grid instead

Comment: if my info helped you an accept for the answer would be awesome! thx dude!